# Thermal imaging

Tags: electromagnetism, thermodynamics, optics

If we have thermal imaging camera and the sound is wave is produced and propagates in hot air can  we see the electromagnetic emission of molecules producing pressure packets of sound wave?

Answer (score 1):

Gas radiates, and even something as cold as Jupiter is visible in IR.  Even rocket thrusters and jet engines sometimes have visible standing waves - see wikipedia's "Shock Diamond" entry.

If your hot air is not especially hot and your pressure waves are not especially intense, you'll need an exceptional IR camera that is fast and sensitive.   Or perhaps consider working with a standing wave.  Or try image frame stacking statisical analysis methods - record the same event hundreds of times from the same viewpoint with slight changes in timing and ImageDifference[ImageAdd[allonejiffyimages],ImageAdd[alltwojiffyimages]] in mathematica over the length of captured frames.   A jiffy is about a 60th of a second, not the most common unit.  Good luck.

Comment: So Actually in theory the sound wave becomes visible in microwave or infrared spectrum since air emits in this region